# Express: 500 ReferenceError <function name> not definied error

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have app.js with following code:

```
      var express    = require('express')
          , siteVersion = require('./lib/helpers.js').siteVersion;
```

helpers.js:

```
     exports.helpers = {
          siteVersion: function(name, version) {
         return name + ' v' + version;
         },

         appName: 'Nodepad',
         version: '0.1'
      };
```

index.jade:

head

## {siteVersion(appName, version)}

body

Getting error:

Express: 500 ReferenceError siteVersion not definied error

Appreciate help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
siteVersion = require('./lib/helpers.js').siteVersion;
```

To:

```
siteVersion = require('./lib/helpers.js').helpers.siteVersion;
```

Comment: This what I have in app.js

 var sys = require('sys');
 var http = require('http');
 var url  = require('url');
 var check = require('validator').check,
     sanitize = require('validator').sanitize;

 var express    = require('express')
   , dispatcher = require('./lib/dispatcher.js')
   , siteVersion = require('./lib/helpers.js').helpers.siteVersion;

 var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

Comment: app.configure(function(){
   app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
   app.set('view engine', 'jade');
   app.use(express.bodyParser());
   app.use(express.cookieParser());
   app.use(express.session({key: 'some-key', secret: 'some-We1rD sEEEEEcret!'}));
   app.use(require('connect').bodyParser());
   app.use(express.methodOverride());
   app.use(app.router);
   app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
 });